# How to compare if the two newest files in a directory are identical using a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, timestamp, file-comparison

I'm looking for a simple way to have an `if` statement where the conditional is whether the 2 newest files in a given directory (recursively) are identical in contents.

Comment: This is really two questions in one: (1) get the names of two newest files in a directory (recursive or not? Not clear); (2) compare two files given their paths. (2) is very easy (`diff`, `cmp`, etc.). (1) as far as I know is not so easy. There's `ls -t`, but parsing `ls` output is always frowned upon; then there's `stat`, but you might need to manually sort the timestamps.

Comment: Yes, it is 2 questions in one. And this is why it's not a duplicate of the linked-to question. I could put an answer in a comment, but I think it's worth re-opening the question. After all, I landed here because I had exactly the same question.

Comment: The short answer is: `readarray -t files < <(ls -t /your/dir/ | head -2); if diff -q "${files[@]}"; then echo identical; fi`. If you are certain that the file names can never contain spaces, you can do the simpler `files=$(ls -t /your/dir/ | head -2); if diff -q $files; then echo identical; fi`. But one day, there will be a space in a file name...

Answer (score 0):

One way of making the comparison for files contained within a directory in bash without parsing `ls` is:

```
unset -v penultimate  ## one before newest
unset -v latest       ## newest

for file in "$dirname"/*; do
    [[ $file -nt $latest ]] && penultimate="$latest" && latest="$file"
done

if [[ -f $latest ]] && [[ -f $penultimate ]]; then
    if diff -q "$penultimate" "$latest" ; then
        printf "Files '%s' and '%s' are identical\n" "$penultimate" "$latest"
    fi
fi
```

**Note:** if the files differ, the default behavior of `diff -q` will output: `Files '%s' and '%s' differ\n" "$penultimate" "$latest"`. Also note, the above compares for the existence of 2 files and not whether either of the newest two are symbolic links. It further does not compare the contents of subdirectories for the given directory.